# Switching to wrapfig2 causes: ! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }

Tags: errors

I have a, rather large, latex project which I want to switch from wrapfig to wrapfig2. However this results in  `! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }`

Minimal reproducer:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{buildinfo}
\NewDocumentCommand \myBuildDate{} {2024-01-10}
\NewDocumentCommand \myBuildGitHead{} {main}
\NewDocumentCommand \myBuildGitDesc{} {a5f41d1788c5+}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  listof=totoc,
%  12pt,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\usepackage[
  mode=buildnew
]{standalone}
\usepackage[draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\makeatletter
% Set a footer with build information if 'final' package option is *not* provided.
\@ifclasswith{scrbook}{final}{}{%
  % Generated .buildinfo with macros like \myBuildDate{} and
  % \myBuildGitDesc{}.
  \input{buildinfo}

  % Set a footer using scrlayer-scrpage with the build information.
  \cfoot*{\scriptsize \textcolor{red}{\myBuildDate{} --- \myBuildGitHead{} --- \myBuildGitDesc{}}}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{wrapfig2}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \BlackCircled{m} {\CircledParamOpts{outer color=black,fill color=black!90,inner color=white}{1}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  Minimal
\end{document}
```

Note that removing the circled package fixes it, and so does removing the `\@ifclassswith` block.

**`minimal.log`**:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023 Gentoo Linux)  (format=lualatex 2023.12.29)  10 JAN 2024 13:48
 system commands enabled.
**minimal.tex
(./minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-23>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
[…]
LaTeX Warning: Writing or overwriting file `buildinfo'.


\openout127 = buildinfo.tex

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box51
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 135.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrbook)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 2691
.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/flo/.texlive/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip49
\ta@div=\count184
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `a4paper'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `paper=a4'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `paper=a4' there
(typearea)             instead of `a4paper', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip50
\ta@vblk=\skip51
\ta@temp=\skip52
\footheight=\skip53
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1799.
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\chapter on input line 5990.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 6001.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 6001.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrbook)           for `\part on input line 6010.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 6020.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 6020.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 6030.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 6030.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 6041.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 6041.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip60
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 6051.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 6051.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip61
\belowcaptionskip=\skip62
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box52
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 7242.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@figure=\count192
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 7259.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip64
\c@table=\count193
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7430.
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/xr-hyper.sty
Package: xr-hyper 2023-10-21 v7.01c eXternal References (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.sty
Package: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Package to include TeX sub-files with prea
mbles

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/04/15 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count194
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty
Package: currfile 2022/10/10 v0.8 Provides the file path elements of the curren
t input file

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2022/10/25 v0.8b Hooks for input files

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty
Package: filehook-2020 2022/10/25 v0.8b Hooks for input files
))
\c@currfiledepth=\count195
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gincltex/gincltex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty
Package: svn-prov 2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
)
Package: gincltex 2011/09/04 v0.3 Include external LaTeX files like graphics

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
Package: adjustbox 2022/10/17 v1.3a Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
Package: trimclip 2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen140
\Gin@req@width=\dimen141
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty
Package: collectbox 2022/10/17 v0.4c Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box53
)
\tc@llx=\dimen142
\tc@lly=\dimen143
\tc@urx=\dimen144
\tc@ury=\dimen145

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pgf.def
File: tc-pgf.def 2019/01/04 v2.2 trimclip fall-back clipping driver using PGF

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks20
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen146
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen147

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box54
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen148
\pgf@y=\dimen149
\pgf@xa=\dimen150
\pgf@ya=\dimen151
\pgf@xb=\dimen152
\pgf@yb=\dimen153
\pgf@xc=\dimen154
\pgf@yc=\dimen155
\pgf@xd=\dimen156
\pgf@yd=\dimen157
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count196
\c@pgf@countb=\count197
\c@pgf@countc=\count198
\c@pgf@countd=\count199
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count266

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count267
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count268
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 227.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen158
\pgfmath@count=\count269
\pgfmath@box=\box55
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270
)) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen159
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@picminy=\dimen161
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen163
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen164
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen165
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen166
\pgf@xx=\dimen167
\pgf@xy=\dimen168
\pgf@yx=\dimen169
\pgf@yy=\dimen170
\pgf@zx=\dimen171
\pgf@zy=\dimen172
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen173
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen174
) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen175
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen176
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfpic=\box56
\pgf@hbox=\box57
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box58
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count271
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen177
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen178
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen179
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen180
) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen181
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@max=\dimen182
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count272
\pgf@shadingcount=\count273
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box59
))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box60
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen183
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen184
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
Package trimclip Info: No clipping driver 'tc-luatex.def' available.
(trimclip)             Using fall-back PGF driver.
)
\adjbox@Width=\dimen185
\adjbox@Height=\dimen186
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen187
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen188
\adjbox@pwidth=\dimen189
\adjbox@pheight=\dimen190
\adjbox@pdepth=\dimen191
\adjbox@ptotalheight=\dimen192
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty
Package: ifoddpage 2022/10/18 v1.2 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count274
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box61
\sift@deathcycles=\count275
\@vwid@loff=\dimen193
\@vwid@roff=\dimen194
))
\gincltex@box=\box62
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filemod/filemod-expmin.sty
Package: filemod-expmin 2011/09/19 v1.2 Get and compare file modification times
 (expandable; minimal)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks30
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
Package: scrlayer-scrpage 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (end user interf
ace for scrlayer)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty
Package: scrlayer 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (defining layers and pag
e styles)
Package scrlayer Info: patching LaTeX kernel macro \pagestyle on input line 218
3.
)
Package scrlayer-scrpage Info: Makeing stand-alone element `pagehead' from
(scrlayer-scrpage)             alias to `pageheadfoot' on input line 1106.
) (./buildinfo.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig2/wrapfig2.sty
Package: wrapfig2 2023-09-03 v.6.2.1 Wrap text around figures, tables, framed t
ext blocks

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-10-23 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-10-23 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count276
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
))
Package: xparse 2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty
Package: xfp 2023-10-10 L3 Floating point unit
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count277
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count278
\float@exts=\toks31
\float@box=\box64
\@float@everytoks=\toks32
\@floatcapt=\box65
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/curve2e/curve2e.sty
Package: curve2e 2023-07-04 v.2.3.1 Extension package for pict2e

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
Package: pict2e 2020/09/30 v0.4b Improved picture commands (HjG,RN,JT)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg
File: pict2e.cfg 2016/02/05 v0.1u pict2e configuration for teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package pict2e Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 112.
Package pict2e Info: Driver file for pict2e: p2e-luatex.def on input line 114.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-luatex.def
File: p2e-luatex.def 2016/02/05 v0.1u Driver-dependant file (RN,HjG,JT)
)
\pIIe@GRAPH=\toks33
\@arclen=\dimen195
\@arcrad=\dimen196
\pIIe@tempdima=\dimen197
\pIIe@tempdimb=\dimen198
\pIIe@tempdimc=\dimen199
\pIIe@tempdimd=\dimen256
\pIIe@tempdime=\dimen257
\pIIe@tempdimf=\dimen258
)
\@tdA=\dimen259
\@tdB=\dimen260
\@tdC=\dimen261
\@tdD=\dimen262
\@tdE=\dimen263
\@tdF=\dimen264
\defaultlinewidth=\dimen265
\PbDim=\skip65
\legendbox=\box66
\MV@C=\count279
)
\@float@every@text=\toks34
\c@text=\count280
\wrapoverhang=\dimen266
\WF@size=\dimen267
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count281
\WF@box=\box67
\NWF@box=\box68
\WF@everypar=\toks35
\WF@correctlines@switch=\count282
\insertwidth=\dimen268
\radius=\dimen269
\WFinsertwidthL=\dimen270
\WFinsertwidthH=\dimen271
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/circledsteps/circledsteps.sty
Package: circledsteps 2023/08/11 v1.3.3 Circled steps that you can reference

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/picture/picture.sty
Package: picture 2020-04-22 v1.6 Dimens for picture macros (HO)
Package picture Info: Calculation method: etex.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
\csteps@CBox=\box69
\csteps@XLength=\skip66
\csteps@YLength=\skip67
\csteps@YDepth=\skip68
\csteps@tmplen=\skip69
\c@cstepcnt=\count283
)
(./minimal.aux)
\openout1 = minimal.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3
8.
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \partname on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \chaptername on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \appendixname on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \figurename on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \tablename on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \contentsname on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listfigurename on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listtablename on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \bibname on input line 38.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \indexname on input line 38.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count284
\scratchdimen=\dimen272
\scratchbox=\box70
\nofMPsegments=\count285
\nofMParguments=\count286
\everyMPshowfont=\toks36
\MPscratchCnt=\count287
\MPscratchDim=\dimen273
\MPnumerator=\count288
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count289
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks37
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 40.

! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.40 \end{document}
                 
? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.40 \end{document}
                 
? X


Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 17352 strings out of 476729
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated 4393 words of node memory still in use:
   82 hlist, 30 vlist, 31 rule, 4 disc, 27 local_par, 5 dir, 12 math, 179 glue, 
9 kern, 28 penalty, 48 glyph, 152 attribute, 59 glue_spec, 152 attribute_list, 5
 temp, 2 if_stack, 2 write, 21 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:1,5:45,7:4,8:1,9:1,10:6,11:2
 38667 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 27 fonts using 1608751 bytes
 140i,19n,131p,10901b,497s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.

PDF statistics: 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Hi! I (the author of circledsteps) have no error from this code... maybe some version mismatch?

Comment: @Flow can you show your .log file? Your example works fine for me, too.

Comment: I get no error from the posted code in texlive 2023

Comment: @Rmano I get an error if I actually use the \BlackCircled command.

Comment: load circlesteps before wrapfig2

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you're right (as ever!). It seems that the problem is that `pict2e` and `picture` must be loaded before `wrapfig2`...

Comment: well the actual culprit is curve2e (loaded by wrapfig2). All this packages fight around the \put command ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you write an answer?